How can I establish a secure connection as a server in Unity (SSL)?
My main issue is that I can't load a X509Certificate2 in order to use SSL encryption in Unity.
I'm currently using Unity Editor 2021.3.5f1. Changing the Unity version is a not a viable solution for me.
So what I have tried.

Loading the certificate straight up:

X509Certificate2 serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2("c:/my/path/server_pfx.pfx");

This has failed as I get the a Format Exception

FormatException: Only integer can be converted Mono.Security.ASN1Convert.ToInt32

The certificate was created by using
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out server_pfx.pfx -macalg sha1


Loading the certificate withouth a private key and adding the private key in C#

X509Certificate2 pubOnly = new X509Certificate2("c:/my/path/cert.pem");
// Loading the prviate Key.
string privateKeyPem = File.ReadAllText("c:/my/path/key.pem");
RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
var privateKey = privateKeyPem.Replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----",string.Empty).Replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", string.Empty);
privateKey = privateKey.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);
rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(privateKeyBytes, out int _);
    
// Now creating the certificate with the private key.
X509Certificate2 pubWithPrivate = pubOnly.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);
this.serverCertificate = new 
X509Certificate2(pubWithPrivate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx));

This doesn't work either because the rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey throws a PlatformNotSupported Exception.

I have tried to use Unity Transport. The version is 1.0.0.
I install the package but when I get to this line of code:

var settings = new NetworkSettings();
settings.WithSecureServerParameters(
    certificate: SecureParameters.MyGameServerCertificate,
    privateKey: SecureParameters.myGameServerPrivateKey
);

From here
I get a compilation error saying that WithSecureServerParameters does not exist. As far as I've been able to tell the function is available on Version 1.0.0 of Unity Transport, so I've no idea what do.
Can anyone tell me a fix for ANY of these issues? Or Provide me with another thing to try?

You don't need a private key for establishing a TLS connection to a server. It is only needed it you want to do TLS with public key client authentication. But you never mention something like this in your post.

I'm not establishing connection to a server. I want this code to BE the server. Not sure if we are talkign about the same. Thing. If don't do this when I try, sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer I get the exception that there is not privte key.

Sorry, this was a misunderstanding. Because of your title I thought you want to establish a connection as a vlient. Servers do not establish connections, they accept them.

@Robert Thank you. Ironically enought I need to code both the client and the server in different languages. I tried switching over to be the client but I couldn't get anywhere either (Different errors). I'm trying something else though. Thank you.
